# How to change the use of Common Lisp `with-open-file` so that elements are appended inside a list in a file?

Tags: file, io, format, append, common-lisp

I am using Common Lisp (SBCL). Currently, I can write a file appending lists. In order to illustrate, let's first define some variables to make it easier to understand:

```lisp
(defvar example-1 '((d-1 u-1) (i-1) (i-2)))
(defvar example-2 '((d-2 u-2) (i-1) (i-2)))
```

Now, in the REPL:

```lisp
CL-USER> (with-open-file (str "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/stack-overflow.lisp"
                         :direction :output
                         :if-exists :append
                         :if-does-not-exist :create)
           (format str " ~S ~%" example-1))
    
CL-USER> (with-open-file (str "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/stack-overflow.lisp"
                         :direction :output
                         :if-exists :append
                         :if-does-not-exist :create)
           (format str " ~S ~%" example-2))
```

If I go to checkout the file "stack-overflow.lisp", I can see:

```
 ((D-1 U-1) (I-1) (I-2)) 
 ((D-2 U-2) (I-1) (I-2))
```

Ok. This is **close to what I want**.

However, I would like to have everything wrapped in a list:

```
(

 ((D-1 U-1) (I-1) (I-2)) 
 ((D-2 U-2) (I-1) (I-2)) 

)
```

Thus, every time something is "appended" to the file, it should be inside this list. I am changing this because it will make this file easier to read and work on. I will need to filter the elements added.

What do I need to change in `with-open-file` function to have this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single call to `WITH-OPEN-FILE` and combine everything into a single list.

```
(with-open-file (str "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/stack-overflow.lisp"
                         :direction :output
                         :if-exists :overwrite
                         :if-does-not-exist :create)
  (pprint (list example-1 example-2) str))
```

If you want to append to the list every time you write, you need to read the list, append to the list, then overwrite the file with the updated list.

```
(defun append-to-list-in-file (filename new-item &aux contents) ;;;;
  (setq contents (list)) ;; default in case reading fails
  (ignore-errors
    (with-open-file (str filename :direction :input)
      (setq contents (read str))))
  (setq contents (nconc contents (list new-item)))
  (with-open-file (str filename :direction :output :if-exists :overwrite)
    (write contents :stream str)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I cannot use the first option. My case is the second one. One question:  Why you did not include the keywords used in my original post `:if-exists :append :if-does-not-exist :create` ? Are they useless in my application?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, reading it will fail. And we don't want to append, we want to overwrite, which is the default for output.

Comment: I've added error handling so if the file doesn't exist, we'll append to a default empty list.

Comment: Great. This error handling is needed indeed. I think there is a small typo in your solution on the parenthesis before the function name. I will edit it.

Comment: I cannot edit just the possible typo. it was mandatory to change at least 6 characters. Thus, I added some ";;;;".

Comment: Not sure if it works. I tried it with a file did not exist: `(append-to-list-in-file
          "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/sol.lisp"
          3)` . The file was (i) created, (ii) written with a `NIL`. I was expecting the file to be created *and* have a new list such that '( 3 ).

Comment: `nconc` can't modify in place when the value is NIL, forgot to assign back to the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The previous bug with `'(3)` was fixed. However, I cannot append the file's list. If I do: `(append-to-list-in-file  "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/CL.lisp" 4)` it works. The code creates the file AND puts `'(4)` inside of it. However, if I run the code again with a new element using the file that was just created: `(append-to-list-in-file  "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/CL.lisp" 5)` it throws an error: `Error opening #P"/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/CL.lisp"
   [Condition of type SB-EXT:FILE-EXISTS]` . I was expecting:  `'(4 5)`.